# Sorting in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, psql

Sorting product by master price not working in my project.
I use standart spree install.

Modified part of taxons_controller.rb show method:

```
@searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(taxon: @taxon.id, include_images: true))
@products = @searcher.retrieve_products
binding.pry
@products = @products.reorder('').send(:descend_by_master_price)
```

When in pry console i write `@products.reorder('').send(:descend_by_master_price)`, i get the following: `<Module:0x007f1e0048daa8>:0x3f8f041276b8>`.

But if i write `Product.all.reorder('').send(:descend_by_master_price)` everything work fine.

And in case of `@products.reorder('').send(:descend_by_master_price).last`, i get the errror:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...UB' AND "spree_products"."id" IN (5, 1)  ORDER BY "spree_pri...
```

So the issue is in DISTINCT...

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the ORDER BY fields in your select clause.
Try using,

```
@products.select('spree_products.*, spree_prices.amount').reorder('').send(:descend_by_master_price)
```

Comment: Oh, such a simple solution! Thank u!